# How to make ArrayAdapter populate 2 Arraylists within the same ListView

Tags: android, string, android-listview, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I want to make 2 `ArrayList<Strings>`s of the same length, appear, like this, in 1 `ListView`

Word 1 is a `TextView` that should be populated with 1 `ArrayList<String>` and Word 2 is another `TextView` that should be populated with a different `ArrayList<String>`

***These are** `TextViews`, **not** `Button`**s**

[image: Word 1 is an <code>ArrayList</code>, Word 2 is another <code>ArrayList</code>]

What should my `ArrayAdaptor` look like?

If this is a duplicate please send me a link.

**CustomArrayAdapter.java that displays the same `ArrayList<String>` on both sides (Not what I need)**

```
public class CustomArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
private ArrayList<String> words1;
private ArrayList<String> words2;

public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> words1, ArrayList<String> words2) {
    this.words1 = words1;
    this.generates = words2;
    this.context = context;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }

    String a = (String) getItem(position);
    String b = (String) getItem(position);

    TextView tv1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.rhymed_word);
    TextView tv2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.generated_word);

    tv1.setText(a);
    tv2.setText(b);

    return v;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return words1.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    if (position >= words1.size())
        return words2.get(position);
    return words1.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}
```

}

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, could you elaborate? Do you just want one button.setText() to come from one ArrayList and the other button2.setText() to come from a different ArrayList?...because that description in itself is kind of the answer...Or are they just TextViews. They look like buttons, but it should work the same either way.

Comment: Please see my changes to the post. Thank you

Comment: Right, but what about my first question? Do you want, say, the TextView on the left to come from one ArrayList<String> and the one on the right to come from a different ArrayList<String> for every row? Do you have an xml or any code, or do you just want a starting point?

Comment: Added some code that is giving a weird output.

Comment: Ok, I see the predicament. The position in getView() is the position of the listView the items are on. I'll post some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, instead of using the Overridden method, just do this:

```
TextView tv1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.rhymed_word);
TextView tv2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.generated_word);

tv1.setText(words1.get(position));
tv2.setText(words2.get(position));

return v;
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, you want to display word1 from one ArrayList and word2 from another ArrayList. ArrayAdapter does not work in your case because you have two arrays to display for each row. One approach is to derive a class from BaseAdapter and implements getView(). Here is part of the class implementation:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View v = convertView;
    if(v == null) {
         // Inflate a layout for your listview row
    }

    // Assuming the 2 arrays are words1 and words2
    // Assuming the textviews are word1 and word2
    word1.setText(words1[position]);
    word2.setText(words2[position]);

    return v;
}

@Override
public int getCount()
{
    return words1.size();
}
```